Static Routing Only Ping In One Direction
We have 2 PFSense routers. R1 is the edge router and R2 is behind the edge. The goal is to get computers on opposite ends to communicate with each other. Here is how the networks are configured. Refer to the attached image for a map.

R1 ROUTES
Destination Network: 192.168.1.0/24
Subnet Mask: 24
Gateway: 10.0.5.3 (R2's WAN IP on R1's LAN)

R1 FIREWALL
WAN: Default
LAN: Allow All

R2 FIREWALL
WAN: Allow All
LAN: Allow All

R2 NAT
Outbound Mode: Hybrid
Mapping Interface: WAN
Source: 192.168.1.0/24
Destination: 10.0.2.0/29
Upstream Gateway: 10.0.5.1
Translation Targer: Interface Address

Here are the results
R1 ping 10.0.2.1
SUCCESS

R1 ping 10.0.5.3
SUCCESS

R1 ping 192.168.1.1
FAILURE

R2 ping 10.0.5.1
SUCCESS

R2 ping 10.0.2.1
SUCCESS

R2 ping 192.168.1.1
SUCCESS

Tracing route to 192.168.1.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.2.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.



Your diagram has R1 with three connections, but your post only mentions two interfaces ("WAN" and "LAN"). Which of those is correct? How are the two actually interconnected? 2) What's the purpose of the NAT configuration in R2? I can't make any sense of it. Is it supposed to be in place of routes or something?


Why do you need NAT on R2?

A I supposed to create a static route on R2? I can remove the NAT. R2 can successfully reach everything it needs to already.

NAT is a kludge to extend the life of IPv4; it is not a substitute for routing. You only NAT where you must (public<->private or overlapping IPv4 addressing). Inside your own network, you should only route. You could use static routes, but they do not scale. A routing protocol, such as OSPF, is easy enough. to configure, and it is dynamic and scales.

I'll stick to using static routes. R1 is configured correctly right? And R2 should not need one since it can already ping everything right?

I just thought of something. My static route would not know the gateway IP of the network it is being sent to. Could that have something to do with the issue?

@daniellooartist no. Routing works by knowing the next hop. Also, get a book on TCP/IP.

The solution was to delete the route. Went to Diagnostics > Routes and the route was stuck. It never got removed. The gateway was also labeled as a link interface rather than an actual gateway IP.
Simply deleting the static route, restarting the router from the CLI and recreating the route in that exact order fixed the issue.
